# Linq problem when trying a left join projection with multiple records

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-entities

I'm trying to do a left join in linq to a table that has a one to many relationship. I need to set the collection property, but i can't make it to work
some example of my code is (i changed the entity names) :

```
context =>
   from entity1 in context.EntityOnes
   join comment in context.Comments on entity1.Id equals comment.CommentSourceId into tmpComments
   from comment in tmpComments.DefaultIfEmpty()
   select new EntityOneData
       {
           EntityOne = entity1,
           EntityOneComments = tmpComments
       };
```

When i'm retrieving the data for the query, i get a nullreferenceexception. the database is empty, but the DefaultIfEmpty should bring at least an empty collection, not return null

```
EntityOneComments is an IEnumerable<Comment>
```

I've also tried doing the last line like

```
EntityOneComments = tmpComments.ToList()
```

but to no avail, i got a strange error like this :

```
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Collections.Generic.List1[RecipeCategoryItem] ToList[RecipeCategoryItem](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable1[RecipeCategoryItem])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

Comment: You realize, that you are using the variable name `comment` twice, for two different things? Maybe that's the problem?

Comment: sorry? what do you mean? i don't get it

Comment: `join comment in context.Comments` and `from comment in tmpComments.DefaultIfEmpty()`. You are using the variable name `comment` twice. However, I am not sure that this is the problem.

Comment: i don't think so, that's how you implement a join with the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code with empty collections, and I didn't get a `NullReferenceException`, so there are really only three possibilities:

1. `context` is `null`
2. `context.EntityOnes` contains at least one `null` object
3. `context.Comments` contains at least one `null` object

If your database is really empty as you say, the only reason for the `NullReferenceException` can be reason 1.

Comment: @Daniel: Check my answer again. These are the three ONLY possibilities there are for a NRE, if it really happens in the code, you showed us.

Comment: damn, you were right. this is why i hate mocks (when they're not correctly defined). yes, the comments were null :S
but now i have another problem, i may create a new question for it, because i'm getting a stackoverflowexception when running the query

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding what you are trying to achieve, but Linq does automaticaly follow 1..n relationships and makes Fields in the object to represent them. Consider this construction:

Entity

Comment

Where 1 `Entity` has many `Comment`s.
Then in Linq the object representing `Entity` has a field `Comments`, which contains a collection of all the comments that have their foreign key set to the Entity's primary key. This is the default behaviour for Linq.

Therefore I think that your code should be something like this:

```
var entitiesWithComments = context.Where(entity => entity.Comments.Count > 0);
```

Now you can iterate over the collection `entitiesWithComments` and each object in it is an `Entity` with the field `Comments` which contains the comments to this entity.

Comment: i know what you mean, but it's not the case. the entity won't have in the entity model a relation to the comment (it was designed like that, and i can't change it). so i need to do a query against the context and create a projection that joins them in the same type of object.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is more prosaic than what you "debug" it to be. This `DefaultIfEmpty` override returns null because TSource is a reference type and default value for a reference type is null. So the error is in the assumption that the method will generate a "default" instance of the TSource.